# Rails 3 and Devise - Sign out not working after converting app to Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

My routes

```
devise_for :users
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config #I have also tried removing this for any conflicts
resources :users
```

The sign out link. Routes to `/users/sign_out` just fine

```
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

Trying to sign out, gives me the error:

```
Couldn't find User with id=sign_out
```

If I then remove the resource :users, I get:

```
The action 'sign_out' could not be found for UsersController
```

What's wrong? The exact same code worked with `Rails 2.3.8 and` the corresponding `Devise` version

Logging in etc. works fine.

My setup is:

- Ruby 1.9.2
- Rails 3.1.1.rc3
- Devise 1.4.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, using the same path for UsersController and Devise isn't a great idea. I would suggest using a path like '/accounts' for Devise.

But this probably isn't the cause of your sign out problem, as `devise_for :users` comes before `resources :users` in routes.rb. What seems to be the cause is, unless there'a typo in the question, that there's no comma after `destroy_user_session_path`. `:method => :delete` will be interpreted as a parameter to `destroy_user_session_path` unless there's a comma.

Also, make sure you're including jquery and jquery_ujs in application.js, as these are required for `:method => :delete` to work.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Do you mean like this:
devise_for :users, :path => "account" ?
Then I get the error: No route matches [GET] "/account/sign_out".
Rake routes says: destroy_user_session DELETE /account/sign_out(.:format)                                      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}

Comment: @Frexuz if that was a typo, and you have changed the path, then you're either not including jquery or jquery isn't working for some reason.

Comment: You are correct. I did not load the rails jquery gem correctly. Thank you!